# How to obtain the list of return fields in the resolver which are defined in the graphQL query?

Tags: node.js, graphql

Let's say I have this GraphQL query:

```
query {
  hello,
  user (id: "12") {
    givenName,
    familyName
  }
}
```

where I only want to return givenName and familyName as a result.

Where can I find givenName and familyName in the resolve function?

None of the arguments provides by the resolve function provides them:

```js
const queryDef = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        id: { type: graphql.GraphQLID },
        givenName: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
        familyName: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
        city: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve: (parent, args, context, info) => {
        console.log('parent  ', parent); // no return fields!
        console.log('args    ', args  ); // no return fields!
        console.log('context ', context); // no return fields!
        console.log('info    ', info); // no return fields!
        return {
          // return only those fiels defined
          // in the query
          
        };
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I only want to return those fields defined as return fields in the query i.e. givenName and familyName but NOT city.

How do I do that? Or more precisely, how can obtain the field names of givenName and familyName in the resolver?

Comment: `info` - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-arguments ... at low scale (single records) simply return all data, server will drop unnecessary props from response

Comment: I apologize and I propably appear like a total moron, but I wouldn't have asked, if I had found this information in the graphql docs.

I still can't find information I am looking for, even though you provided this url to relevant page.

Comment: what was logged for `info`? depends on server implementation, usually it contains an AST fragment ... https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/687

Comment: You're right it's all in info. I just realized the wealth of information in that object. It looked a litte scary first. Thanks!